# getting the current user account-id in boto3

Tags: boto3, botocore

I need to get the [account-id](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html) of the 'current user' in a [`boto3`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) script. Up to now my best solution is to parse the current user [arn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-arns):

```
>>> import boto3
>>> account_id = boto3.resource('iam').CurrentUser().arn.split(':')[4]
```

but I was wondering if there is a more 'lightweight' approach. In fact

```
>>> timeit.timeit("boto3.resource('iam').CurrentUser().arn",
... 'import boto3', number=10)
4.8895583080002325
```

and I actually do not need the [`CurrentUser`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#currentuser) resource in my script.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can get the account ID by using the STS API:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
'012345678901'
```

Comment: This solution is only marginally faster than loading the resource. The only solution I see is to use asynchronous code.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work anymore. I now get `AttributeError: 'STS' object has no attribute 'get_caller_identity'`

Comment: After years this method still works. If you have an error like @Mark, check if your user has the right policy.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There is now an api you can call, see mixja's answer.

First off, there is no way to get the account id straight from `boto3`. There is no information stored locally that can tell you that, and there is no service API that returns it outside the context of an ARN. So there is no way to get it from `boto3` without inspecting an ARN.

Secondly, using `timeit` can be very misleading with `boto3` or `botocore` because there is a bit of warm-up time when you create a client or resource for the first time (the service definitions are loaded on the fly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but let me add that I know that in `boto3` the attributes are lazily evaluated, so that the first access takes longer than the subsequent ones. The point is that my script is used interactively as a CLI, and a delay of about 500ms on the first access results in a "laggish" user experience.

Comment: mixja, this answer was correct at the time of writing. The operation used in your answer was added on April 5th, 2016. I edited my comment to point to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sts            = boto3.client('sts')
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = sts.get_caller_identity()["Account"]

print(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID)
```