# Boto3: Get EC2 images owned by me

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

I would like to get all ami images owned by me. I tried something like below:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
owner_id = 'owner_id'
filters = [{'Name': 'owner-id', 'Values': [owner_id]}]
images = ec2.images.filter(Filters=filters).all()
```

But I need to put owner_id explicid in the code. Is it any solution to do that automatically from aws credentials?

Comment: You want to get the caller id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709461/get-aws-account-id-from-boto

Comment: Thanks @BretzL. It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use self for the owner.  This is what I use.

```
boto3conn = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-west-2")
images = boto3conn.images.filter(Owners=['self'])
```

Comment: how would you add tags to the filter?

Answer (score 3):

This will help, It will show you ALL `AMI` thats `owned` by `your aws account`

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])
for ami in response['Images']:
  print (ami['ImageId'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the STS API to get this information.

I found this post talking about it: [getting the current user account-id in boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332050/getting-the-current-user-account-id-in-boto3)

So the code you need is:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
owner_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
filters = [{'Name': 'owner-id', 'Values': [owner_id]}]
images = ec2.images.filter(Filters=filters).all()
```

Make sure to change the region name to the correct one, or leave it out if you've set it elsewhere in your environment.